# Selfadjoint bounded isometric operators and orthogonal projections

Tags: functional-analysis, projection, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ a Hilbert space, $ T = T^{\star} \in B(H)$ with $ || T || = 1$.
Prove that for any $v\in H$ $ \lim_{n \to \infty} T^nv= Pv$,
where $P\in B(H)$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\text{ker}(Id-T) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.  If $T=\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&-1}$, then
$$
T^n\pmatrix{x\cr y}=\pmatrix{x\cr (-1)^ny},
$$
which does not converge if $y\neq0$.

---

EDIT: From now on let us assume that $T≥0$.

It is well known that  $σ(T)$ consists of a sequence of eigenvalues converging to zero in $[0, 1]$,
including 0 (which may or may not be an eigenvalue).  Moreover the spectral
radius of $T$ coincides with its norm,  so 1 is necessarily in the spectrum of $T$.

Denoting by  $H_λ$ the eigenspace for each $λ∈σ(T)$,  we have that
$$
  H=\bigoplus_{λ∈σ(T)}H_λ = H_1\oplus K,
  $$
where
$$
  K=\bigoplus_{λ∈σ(T)\setminus \{1\}}H_λ.
  $$

Letting $S=T|_K$,  observe that the spectrum of $S$ coincides with $σ(T)\setminus \{1\}$ and, since  1 is necessarily an isolated point of
$σ(T)$, we see that
$σ(S)⊆[0,a]$,
for some $a<1$.  In particular
$$
  \|S\|\leq a<1.
  $$

Observing that $T=I_{H_1}\oplus S$, we have that
$$
  T^n=I_{H_1}\oplus S^n \to I_{H_1}\oplus 0,
  $$
because $\|S^n\|≤\|S\|^n\to 0$.  Finally notice that $I_{H_1}\oplus 0$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H_1$, as desired.

This in fact proves a little more than required, namely that $T$ converges to $I_{H_1}$ in norm.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How would I prove it in the case $T \geq 0$ ?

Comment: thank you very much :)